# Access violation when setting Windows Tags

Tags: tags, windows-api-code-pack

I have a C# all platforms console app to set Windows tags. It is created using VS2022 with code as shown below

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
class TestClass
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    // Display arguments.
    Console.WriteLine(args[0] + " " + args[1]);
    string sFile = args[0];
    string sTagString = args[1];
    
    var shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(sFile);
    string[] sTags = sTagString.Split(';');
        
    shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.AllowSetTruncatedValue = true;
    shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.Value = sTags;
    shellFile.Dispose();

    }
}
```

When I run it with arguments  `"C:\Users\simon\Pictures\Camera Trap\100RECNX\RCNX0025.JPG" NewTag`

it crashes with an access violation at the line

```
shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.Value = sTags;
```

Can anyone suggest how to avoid this problem?

Comment: The problem is that it is an all platforms console app referencing the Microsoft-specific Microsoft.APICodePack.Shell. If I make at a Windows-only console app it works OK.